# How do you create a file programmatically in android studio that opens a link?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, url, createfile

I want to create a file with a button click and then add some code to the file that makes the file add itself to the home screen, and when you click the file, it opens a web URL (like google.com).

I have attempted to use intents in android studio but that did not work on all devices. My API level is 15, so please don't suggest anything I can't use.

Help appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding a shortcut (not a file) to the homescreen but it did not work on all devices.